# Is an incomplete array type compatible with a complete array type?

Tags: arrays, c, types, language-lawyer

Question: are `int (*)[]` and `int (*)[1]` compatible?

Demo 1:

```
typedef int T0;
typedef T0  T1[];
typedef T1* T2[];

T1 x1 = { 13 };
T2 x2 = { &x1 };
```

GCC, Clang, ICC generate no diagnostics.

MSVC generates:

```
<source>(21): warning C4048: different array subscripts: 'T1 (*)' and 'T0 (*)[1]'
```

Note: the `T1 (*)` is `int (*)[]`, the `T0 (*)[1]` is `int (*)[1]`.

Demo 2:

```
int c[][1] = {0};
int (*r)[] = c;
```

GCC, Clang, ICC generate no diagnostics.

MSVC generates:

```
<source>(30): warning C4048: different array subscripts: 'int (*)[0]' and 'int (*)[1]'
```

---

Extra: C2x, 6.7.6.2 Array declarators, 6:

> For two array types to be compatible, both shall have compatible element types, and if both size specifiers are present, and are integer constant expressions, then both size specifiers shall have the same constant value. If the two array types are used in a context which requires them to be compatible, it is undefined behavior if the two size specifiers evaluate to unequal values.

Comment: I feel like I have seen a duplicate recently, but I am having trouble finding it.

Comment: Compatible in which sense? 'c' compiler is very forgiving around arrays and pointers because the language was designed this way. Run-time is what will corrupt memory and crash if you they are not compatible. Some static linters, including clang are trying to warn you in some cases.

Comment: @Serge In the standard's sense. Example: "both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of _compatible types_" (C2x, 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment).

Comment: you have to remember  that `[]` means undefined size.

Comment: What does compiling with MSVC have to do with the C standard?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Trying to understand / guess where this `different array subscripts` comes from.

Comment: @pmor: The point is MSVC does not compile as C. Try Clang with `-x c++` and you will get a similar error message. So experiments with MSVC may not be informative about C rules.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Wow, indeed! Under `-std=c++11` clang++ produces `error: cannot initialize an array element of type 'T1 *' (aka 'T0 (*)[]') with an rvalue of type 'T0 (*)[1]'`, while g++ produces nothing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil And with `-pedantic` g++ produces `warning: conversions to arrays of unknown bound are only available with ‘-std=c++20’ or ‘-std=gnu++20’`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Re: "The point is MSVC does not compile as C": there is `/std:c11` option. If there is a need to compile `.cpp` as C there are `/TC` and `/Tc` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are `int (*)[]` and `int (*)[1]` compatible?

It seems that yes.

C2x, 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type, 5:

> EXAMPLE Given the following two file scope declarations:
>
> ```
> int f(int (*)(), double (*)[3]);
> int f(int (*)(char *), double (*)[]);
> ```
>
> The resulting composite type for the function is:
>
> ```
> int f(int (*)(char *), double (*)[3]);
> ```

and:

> A *composite type* can be constructed from two types that are compatible; ...

Here we see that `double (*)[3]` is the composite type constructed from types `double (*)[3]` and `double (*)[]`.

Hence, the types `double (*)[3]` and `double (*)[]` are compatible.

Hence, the types `int (*)[]` and `int (*)[1]` are compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to complicate things by adding identifiers and typedefs.

```
typedef int T0;
```

`T0` is equivalent to `int` so let's simplify and use `int`.

```
typedef T0 T1[]; ===>  int (T1[]); ===> int T1[];
```

here, `T1` is equivalent to an unspecified array type, so let's simplify and use `int []`.

```
typedef T1* T2[]; ===> int (*T2[])[];
```

This is *an array of pointers to integer arrays*.

Here, `T2` is equivalent to an unspecified array type, so let's simplify and use `int (*[])[]`.

when you write

```
T1 x1 = { 13 }; ===>  int x1[] = { 13 }; ===> int x1[1] = { 13 };
```

as the type is finally completely specified ***by the initializator***, that assigns an array length of one element.

```
T2 x2 = { &x1 }; ===> int (*x2[])[] = { &x1 };
```

where `x1` is of type `int *[1]` (and so `&x1` is of type `int **[1]`.  This will fix the inner array dimension:

```
... ===> int (*x2[1])[];
```

and, as ***there's only one initializer***, this will fix also the outer array dimension:

```
... ===> int (*x2[1])[1];
```

So finally `x2` results in an array of one pointer to array of one `int`.

I'd suggest you to simplify your examples, to be able to understand incomplete type definitions yourself, by using only one incomplete type, and not three levels of them.  This way you would probably be capable of solving the problem without help.