# Conversions to arrays of unknown bound: g++ vs. clang++

Tags: c++, gcc, type-conversion, clang, language-lawyer

Note: this is the follow-up question for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71002121/1778275) question.

Sample code (t334.cpp):

```
typedef int T0;
typedef T0  T1[];
typedef T1* T2[];

T1 x1 = { 13 };
T2 x2 = { &x1 };
```

Invocations:

```
$ g++ t334.cpp -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c
t334.cpp:6:11: warning: conversions to arrays of unknown bound are only available with ‘-std=c++20’ or ‘-std=gnu++20’ [-Wpedantic]
    6 | T2 x2 = { &x1 };
      |           ^~~

$ clang++ t334.cpp -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c
t334.cpp:6:11: error: cannot initialize an array element of type 'T1 *' (aka 'T0 (*)[]') with an rvalue of type 'T0 (*)[1]'
T2 x2 = { &x1 };
          ^~~
```

Can someone explain, what is wrong with this C++ code?

Note: the equivalent C code is valid, because `int (*)[]` and `int (*)[1]` are compatible. Meaning that in C++ they aren't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first definition is of an array of *known* bound that is deduced from the initializer. It has the same effect as:

```
int x1[1] = {13};
```

That means `x1` has type `int[1]`, and `&x1` has type `int (*)[1]`.

The second definition is trying to initialize a variable of type `int (*)[]` from a (brace-enclosed) expression of type `int (*)[1]`. In other words, it requires a conversion from a pointer to array with known bound to a pointer to array with unknown bound.

Just like GCC tells you, this type of conversion only became allowed starting in C++20. If you compile your code with a recent version of Clang with `-std=c++20`, it should compile. See https://godbolt.org/z/4zb5xx658

Comment: In C one of the constraints of simple assignment is "both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types". For `int (*)[]` and `int (*)[1]` such constaint is satisfied because they are compatible. Does it mean that in C++ they aren't compatible?

Comment: @pmor there is no such thing as compatible types in C++.